# Explode PHP Birthday

Tags: php, forms, explode

Below is the dummy code snippet and URL I am passing the birthday value to

```
<?php

list($year,$month,$day)=explode("-", $birthday);

    $url1="http://sdasdasdas.com?bd_y=<?php echo $year ?>"."&bd_m=<?echo $month ?>"."&=bd_d=<?php echo $day ?>"";

    ?>
```

From this form

```
<form name="hmp" style="padding:0px; margin:0px;" method="POST" action="#">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    </div>
<input type="date" name="birthday" placeholder="birthday" id="email" value="" required></input>
<input type="submit" id="sbt" name="submit" class="search-btn-main" value="Get Started">
```

The url populates the birthday/date like this

```
http://sdasdasdas.com?bd_y=%3C?php%20echo%20%20?%3E&bd_m=%3C?php%20echo%20%20?%3E&=bd_d=%3C?php%20echo%20%20?%3E
```

What am I doing here that's not allowing the script to echo the $ values.

Comment: You are opening more <?php tags inside your existing <?php tags so these are just being rendered as part of the string

Comment: Should I make it read -- bd_y=echo $year"."&bd_m=echo $month"."&=bd_d=echo $day"";

Comment: I have provided an answer for you

Answer (score 0):

You are opening more `<?php` tags inside your existing `<?php` tags so these are just being rendered as part of the string. Try this:

```
<?php

list($year,$month,$day)=explode("-", $birthday);

$url1="http://sdasdasdas.com?bd_y=". $year ."&bd_m=" . $month ."&=bd_d=". $day;

?>
```

Edit:

Your comment suggests that $birthday is empty. Have you done the following before the code above?

```
 $birthday = $_POST['birthday'];
```

Comment: @CodyKrecicki see my edited answer, $birthday must be empty, have you set it?